# Extract text with lxml

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I have this text :

```
INTRODUCTION
This is a test document for xml.
I need to extract this sentence.

Conclusion
It should hopefully..
```

The line  `I need to extract this sentence.` is in italics . The xml of the file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\r\n
<w:document 
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
  mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">
   <w:body>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00470EEF" w:rsidRDefault="00456755">
         <w:pPr>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:b/>
            </w:rPr>
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r w:rsidRPr="00456755">
            <w:rPr>
               <w:b/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>INTRODUCTION</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00456755" w:rsidRPr="00B042E3" w:rsidRDefault="00456755">
         <w:pPr>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:color w:val="FFFF00"/>
            </w:rPr>
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r w:rsidRPr="00B042E3">
            <w:rPr>
               <w:color w:val="FFFF00"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>This is a test document for xml.</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00456755" w:rsidRDefault="00E971E1">
         <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:i/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>I need to extract this sentence.</w:t>
         </w:r>
         <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
         <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
      </w:p>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00456755" w:rsidRDefault="00456755"/>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00456755" w:rsidRDefault="00456755">
         <w:pPr>
            <w:rPr>
               <w:b/>
            </w:rPr>
         </w:pPr>
         <w:r w:rsidRPr="00456755">
            <w:rPr>
               <w:b/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>Conclusion</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00456755" w:rsidRPr="00456755" w:rsidRDefault="00456755">
         <w:r w:rsidRPr="00456755">
            <w:t>It should hopefully</w:t>
         </w:r>
         <w:r>
            <w:t>..</w:t>
         </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00456755" w:rsidRPr="00456755">
         <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
         <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
         <w:cols w:space="708"/>
         <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
      </w:sectPr>
   </w:body>
</w:document>
```

I tried :

```
tree = ET.parse(doc_xml)  
[b.tag for b in tree.iterfind(".//i")]
```

The above returns an empty list.

I've searched a lot but wasn't able to figure out how to do that as the text is contained within `<w:i/>`. I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844956/parsing-xml-file-and-extract-cite-in-python) where this was done easily using BeautifulSoup.

Edit: This isn't related exactly but this is an ElementTree approach to extract all text.

```
w = 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' 
    for p in source.findall('.//{' + w + '}p'):
        print ''.join(t.text for t in p.findall('.//{' + w + '}t'))
```

Comment: You probably need to tell it to use the namespace whose URI is `"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"`, by binding a prefix such as `w` to it.

Comment: yes , i've done that already and even extracted all of the text by the 'p' tags and 't' tags..

Comment: Please show us what you've done then. The Python you showed doesn't indicated any use of namespaces.

Comment: I looked at xpath syntaxes and i noticed there is no 'id' here. So how could I zero onto a specific tag?

Comment: @LarsH is the above case possible in lxml ? the path won't always be fixed. something that goes through entire xml and returns text corresponding to the "i"

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you're asking. You say you want the text in the `i` element, but you also say you want "I need to extract this sentence", which is not in an `i` element. Returning the text content of the (first or every) `<i>` element is certainly possible in lxml.

Comment: @LarsH <w:i/> represents italics which i wanted to return . And as you mentioned it is possible , i'm relieved now. Xpath would be the best approach ,right?

Comment: Looks like the above task is impossible for OOXML @LarsH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly modifying the you will get what you want:

```
>>> w = 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'    
>>> for t in tree.findall('.//{%(ns)s}i/../..//{%(ns)s}t' % {'ns': w}):
...     print t.text
... 
I need to extract this sentence.
```

BTW, if you use `local-name()`, you don't need to specify namespace (need to use `xpath` method, which is available in `lxml`):

```
>>> for t in tree.xpath('.//*[local-name()="i"]/../..//*[local-name()="t"]'):
...     print t.text
... 
I need to extract this sentence.
```

**UPDATE**

`..` in the expression selects parent node of the current node. So, `{...}i/../..` will select grand-parent node of `i` node.

Comment: thanks it worked !! Just a question , the xpath looks a bit hard coded (maybe i'm wrong) . Will this extract "i" that comes under any subelement or element in the text?

Comment: thats awesome , it works as intended , sadly i can only upvote once with my profile :P

Comment: @Swordy, I am not good at the file format; my answer is specific to the  xml you gave in the question. If you show me another example that has different format, I can give you more general solution.

Comment: no need bro , i tested it in a couple of documents with different structures and it worked great.. Could you mind adding an explanation of the code?? I dint clearly understand what it does.. especially 2 of those ../..//

Comment: @Swordy, Oops, I missed the most important part of the answer. just added explanation. Thank you for feedbacks.

Comment: is there any site that covers complex structures of xpath or maybe some examples? Because the docs just had the basics..

Comment: @Swordy, I usually reference [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/), [lxml xpath documentation](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html).

Comment: the extraction works but at some places a single word gets split into two due to 2 instances of run tags on that word. Is it possible to take care of it directly or should i use some customized crude methods to join them?

Comment: @Swordy, Could you post a separated question with an example that demonstrate your problem?

Comment: I already have.. Its my latest question and i'm actually studying xslt for it.. it is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057180/word-breaks-in-text-extraction-lxml-xpath)

Answer (score 2):

Building my answer based on your code in Edit section :

```
w = 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main' 
for p in source.findall('.//{' + w + '}p[.//{' + w + '}i]'):
    print ''.join(t.text for t in p.findall('.//{' + w + '}t'))
```

Basically, the first XPath supposed to match all `<w:p>` elements having descendant node `<w:i>`, then as you know the next line extract all `<w:t>` nodes' text from matched `<w:p>` nodes.

Comment: File "<string>", line unknown SyntaxError: invalid predicate

Comment: i guess xpath would fare better on this.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, where is File `<string>` that you mentioned? Parameter of `findall()` methods in above code are XPath...

Comment: i think it is because in "source.findall" , source is an ElementTree object , and I used your code on this object..

Comment: I'm not a python expert, only XPath portion of this question attract me. I assumed your original code on which I'm basing my answer worked for you, is my assumption correct?

Comment: I think in the second line, where you have `p[//...]`, you meant `p[.//...]` (according to your description of what it's supposed to do).

Comment: @har07 what is the type of the variable 'source' in your answer? Because I am getting an error . if i get the type , i can eventually manipulate the input type to get this working..

Comment: @Swordy Honestly, I'm not sure. What is the type of the same variable in your code (the one posted in this question)?

Comment: in the second line , in source.findall , source is of type "ElementTree" which i got by using source = ET.parse(xml_content)

Comment: Just to make sure, simpler XPath : `source.findall('.//{' + w + '}p')` worked fine for you?

Comment: @har07 yes the one in my question worked but your code gives me the invalid predicate error . as mentioned in my first comment.