# Word Breaks in text extraction , Lxml Xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, openxml

I want to extract words with strikethroughs i.e with the `<w:delText>` tag. I have used an expression and it extracts it successfully except that some words appear broken . For example the word `"They"` appears as `'T'` and `'hey'` . Given below is an xml sample where the problem persists:

```
<w:delText
    xml:space="preserve">.
    </w:delText></w:r><w:r
    w:rsidR="0020338C"
    w:rsidDel="00147CFE"><w:rPr><w:rFonts
    w:ascii="Times
    New
    Roman"
    w:hAnsi="Times
    New
    Roman"/><w:sz
    w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:delText>T</w:delText></w:r><w:r
    w:rsidR="00DF6A7D"
    w:rsidDel="00147CFE"><w:rPr><w:rFonts
    w:ascii="Times
    New
    Roman"
    w:hAnsi="Times
    New
    Roman"/><w:sz
    w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:delText>hey</w:delText></w:r></w:del><w:ins
    w:id="5"
    w:author="Author"
    w:date="2014-08-13T10:08:00Z"><w:r
    w:rsidR="00147CFE"><w:rPr><w:rFonts
    w:ascii="Times
    New
    Roman"
    w:hAnsi="Times
    New
    Roman"/><w:sz
    w:val="24"/></w:rPr><w:t
    xml:space="preserve">
    that
    helps
    them</w:t></w:r></w:ins>
```

I used the following code :

```
find =  etree.XPath("//w:p//.//*[local-name() = 'delText']//text()" ,namespaces={'w':"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"})
list_of_deleted_words = (find(lxml_tree))
```

How could i possibly fix this??

**Edit**:

I realized the problem is only with words that have capital letters in them , words like "She" , "He" also get split.

Comment: Well, `delText` does not know of "words", conceptually. You can delete any stretch of text, including whitespace. So, trying to find extracted words is actually meaningless. Except you are very sure that only full words are deleted?

Comment: parts of word can also be deleted and that is extracted well. But in the above case , the enitre word "They" was deleted. Why did it come in separate <delText> tag is another OOXML mystery -_-

Comment: Is your goal to extract **words** (regardless of whether the user deleted them one whole word at a time), or is your goal to extract the chunks that the user deleted?

Comment: It is the words.." They" should be counted as one word rather than two (that my code is doing  currently)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is the words.." They" should be counted as one word rather than two (that my code is doing currently).

The problem arises because stretches of text are arbitrarily put into several so-called "runs". In OOXML, text is organized in `w:p` elements (paragraphs) like this (simplified structures):

```
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Simpli</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>fied structures</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

As you can see, the actual text is inside `w:t`elements that are in turn inside a `w:r` element, or "run". Unfortunately, this division in separate runs is so haphazard that it can be nothing but arbitrary. To my knowledge, nobody knows how the choice for starting a new run is made.

Now, turning to your question, `w:delText` is inside runs, too. And there, too, the fragmenation into runs appears to be purely abitrary.

With your current method, there is no way of knowing if the text content of a particular `w:delText` ever was a whole word or not. For that, you'd have to take into account the whole sequence of runs, both the ones that contain normal text and the ones containing deleted text.

Chances are that this would work, because deleted text is still in a run in the position where it was deleted. Showing OpenXML 2003, slightly different, but it does not matter:

```
<w:r>
  <w:t>Normal Text before deletion </w:t>
</w:r>
<aml:annotation aml:id="0"
               w:type="Word.Deletion"
               aml:author="Mathias Müller"
               aml:createdate="2014-09-26T22:25:00Z">
  <aml:content>
     <w:r wsp:rsidDel="00F647B7">
        <w:delText>T</w:delText>
     </w:r>
  </aml:content>
</aml:annotation>
<aml:annotation aml:id="1"
               w:type="Word.Deletion"
               aml:author="Mathias Müller"
               aml:createdate="2014-09-26T22:24:00Z">
  <aml:content>
     <w:r wsp:rsidDel="00F647B7">
        <w:delText>hey </w:delText>
     </w:r>
  </aml:content>
</aml:annotation>
<w:r>
  <w:t>Normal Text after deletion </w:t>
</w:r>
```

Put another way,

- if there are two "deleted runs" (or more) in a row, with no whitespace in either of them, then you know that they are the parts of just one word.

As for the word boundaries,

- if the deleted run is preceded by a normal run with a whitespace between them (either at the end of the normal run or the beginning of the deleted run) you know that the deleted run started a new word
- if the deleted run is preceded by a normal run without any whitespace, then you should conclude that only a part of the word was deleted and that this deleted run is not a whole word
- all of the above vice versa for a deleted run that is immediately followed by a normal run, with or without whitespace between them.

We all know, of course, that relying on whitespace to tell words apart is a crude method, but it might be sufficient in this case.

Comment: yeah , now i'm thinking of using something like regex over successive run instances.. Any suggestion from your side?

Comment: @Swordy XSLT would be well suited for the task (complex XML manipulation). But if you're uncomfortable with XSLT, I'm sure lxml and Python are a good choice, too. I don't think regexes would do the trick, that would have to be several XPath expressions and conditions (in the manner I have described). But the comments section is not really the place to answer this. Try to write a new version and post a new question if it does not work.

Comment: ohk i'll try that , could u post a link where there are examples of xslt,except for the official lxml site. I'm ready to learn xslt if it is a better option to do the above..

Comment: @Swordy A site I can recommend is this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-introxslt/x-introxslt.html. It requires some knowledge of other programming languages, but that should not be a problem in your case.

Comment: thanks @mathias , I'll study the entire thing and if i have doubts with the approach , i'll ask here and if i have created a code that doesn't work , i'll link my new question here.. :)